# Remote procedure call in C#

Tags: c#, python, web-services, rpc

I am basically new to this kind of work.I am programming my application in C# in VS2010.I have a crystal report that is working fine and it basically gets populated with some xml data. That XMl data is coming from other application that is written in Python on  another machine.

That Python script generates some data and that data is put on the memory stream. I basically have to read that memory stream and write my xml which is used to populate my crystal report. So my supervisor wants me to use remote procedure call.

I have never done any remote procedure calling. But as I have researched and understood. I majorly have to develop a web or WCF service I guess. I don't know how should I do it. We are planning to use the http protocol.

So, this is how it is supposed to work. I give them the url of my service and they would call that service and my service should try to read the data they put on the memory stream. After reading the data I should use part of the data to write my xml and this xml is used to populate my crystal report.

The other part of the data ( other than the data used to write the xml) should be sent to a database on the SQl server. This is my complete problem definition. I need ideas and links that will help me in solving this problem.

Comment: If it's urgent, then you're already too late.

Comment: See [tag:wcf] for some useful links.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a SOAP web service?  Our team has found them much easier than using RPC.

Answer (score 0):

As John wrote, you're quite late if it's urgent and your description is quite vague. There are 1001 RPC techniques and the choice depends on details. But taking into account that you seem just to exchange some xml data, you probably don't need a full RPC implementation. You can write a HTTP server in python with just a few lines of code. If it needs to be a bit more stable and log running, have a look at twisted. Then just use pure html and the WebClient class. Not a perfect solution, but worked out quite well for me more than once. And you said it's urgent! ;-)